# Entities and services

Tags: domain-driven-design

Lets take a scenario where an Order is dispatched and optionally a mail can be sent to the customer depending on an attribute in the Order class. The functionality to send an email is in a service "EmailService".
My question is should the Order.Dispatch method call the EmailService to send the email depending on the attribute in the Order class or should the application layer after calling the Order.Dispatch method call the EmailService? Which is the correct way to do this in DDD?

Thank you.
NN

Answer (score 1):

Domain events allow you to decouple concerns. As soon as an order is dispatched, it could raise a domain event informing interested subscribers. This allows you to make the decision to send an email somwewhere else, so that the order aggregate can remain pure. It often also helps to capture the language better; *when* an order is dispatched, send an email.

```
public class Order 
{
    public Order(string id) 
    {
        Guard.ForEmpty(id, "id");

        Id = id;
    }

    public string Id { get; private set; }

    public void Dispatch() 
    {
        DomainEvents.Raise(new OrderDispatchedEvent());
    }
}

public class MailService : IHandle<OrderDispatchedEvents>
{
    private readonly IMailSender _mailSender:

    public MailService(IMailSender mailSender) 
    {   
        _mailSender = mailSender;
    }

    public void Handle(OrderDispatchedEvent @event) 
    {
        _mailSender.Send(...);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would keep that on the application service layer.  The sending bit may be simple enough in the `Order.Dispatch` as you *could* pass in an instance of the service but how about first of all composing the e-mail?  That is probably somewhat more tricky.

Placing it in the operation script in some application service layer task is one way.  You could also respond to a domain event (`OrderDispatched` for instance) and *then* send.  Another option (when using a service bus) is to publish the `OrderDispatchedEvent` and have you Order endpoint subscribe to that and then send a `SendEMailCommand` to the E-Mail endpoint.

But I would not try to handle the sending in the domain itself as it feels more like output generation as opposed to some business operation/calculation that the domain is typically involved with.  It is a business requirement but just on another level in the same way reporting works.  Although business-related, or process related, it does not necessarily belong in the domain.

Just my ZAR 0.02 :)

Answer (score 0):

[DDD is not a recipe](http://www.sapiensworks.com/blog/post/2013/05/13/7-Biggest-Pitfalls-When-Doing-Domain-Driven-Design.aspx) so there's no correct way to do something.

If by Dispatch you mean that the Order is on the way to the customer (hint: perhaps more accurate semantics are needed here) then the Application layer which sets the Order status as Dispatched can also ask a NotificationService to notify the customer.

I believe that a Domain Event approach is the best though, so once the Order has been dispatched, the OrderDispatched event will be published and a notification service could subscribe to it and will notify the customer using the EmailService, SMSService etc

But the Order itself has nothing to do with this. Some other domain object decides when an Order should be dispatched, it sends a DispatchOrder command to a Domain service which will do the dispatching and then it will generate the OrderDispatched event. This means that your Order shouldn't have a Dispatch method as it's not the Order that does the dispatching. A simple Status property is enough.